# Pentaho Kettle yells SQL Script error that Oracle doesn't

Tags: sql, oracle, etl, pentaho, kettle

I have an ETL process which executes dozens of SQL query tasks.

One specifically keeps throwing an error: `"ORA-01843: not a valid month"` to one of my queries, however the very same query runs normally on PL/SQL. I have even created a procedure with a version of the same query, it also runs smoothly, but calling this procedure from pentaho keeps throwing the same error. Please, anyone have any idea why is pentaho presenting a query error that PL/SQL is not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I feel like its a tool problem. some tools are forgiving and convert date/time/number etc without any error. Some tools are sensitive. I suggest please convert to date properly and do not depend on auto conversion. if that doesnt help then data may have wrong date format.

Comment: Probably different NLS settings. Or your stored procedure initializes the NLS environment while Kettle doesn't

Comment: Use [date/timestamp literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) instead of string that looks like a date, and all should be fine

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language. Did you mean the desktop tool [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I tried a lot of sql options, to no result, until I altered the session NLS parameter that solved the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name,thanks for the info, due to some research in your lead I was able to solve this within the advanced connection configuration in kettle! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @astentx! I tried that too but it didn't work in this case, thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi @WilliamRobertson! You are right, thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('01-FEB-03', 'DD-MON-RR') FROM DUAL;
```

Then, on an English database with the default settings, the query works

Then you change your session settings:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR';
```

And run the same query:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('01-FEB-03', 'DD-MON-RR') FROM DUAL;
```

You will get the error:

> ```
> ORA-01843: not a valid month
> ```

There are three solutions to this:

1. Use the same settings for both queries - this is not a robust solution as you may specify the settings for some services and then it works for a while but then a new developer comes along and connects a new service and does not know of the required settings and suddenly everything is breaking.
2. Specify the settings to use in the query.

   ```sql
   SELECT TO_DATE(
            '01-FEB-03',
            'DD-MON-RR',                -- Specify the format
            'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English' -- Specify the language
          )
   FROM DUAL;
   ```
3. Use a date literal (which is agnostic of the settings):

   ```sql
   SELECT DATE '2003-02-01' FROM DUAL;
   ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b267d9a08eaa7a008dfa05c309fa5762)*

Comment: Hi! You are right and that solved the problem. in my approach I used the first option due tu simplicity, since I could configure the kettle connection to automatically set the NLS parameters every connection, that was faster than changing  a lot of queries and documentation should avoid future problems.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @FagnerRotter Please (1) Document everything so new developers know what you did and why; and (2) start implementing either option #2 or #3 in future queries so that you do not keep increasing the technical debt that you will, at some point down the line, have to invest time and effort to "fix" with a more robust solution.